# Filtering rows in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would need to find the common users which have

- a pattern AA in CODE;
- a pattern `__` in CODE;
- numbers in CODE;

The dataset looks like:

```
User_ID       CODE

A12          AAada __fa
F453         21 ads
J43          Has AA 
...          ...
H21          MNasdf
L32          sad 21
M54          43__12 asd
...          ...
```

What I should do is:

- find first all the user IDs which have AA in CODE, i.e. A12 and J43;
- find all the users which have `__` in CODE, i.e. A12 and M54;
- find all the users which have numbers in CODE, i.e. F453, L32 and M54.

I have tried to filtering the users using regex with `^[^0-9]*$` in case of numbers (but also `df.CODE.str.contains('^\d+\'`)would be fine) and `/[$-/:-?{-~!"^_[]]/` in case of `__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `|` (or) with `str.contains()` with `|` separating the three patterns:

```
df = df[df['CODE'].str.contains('\d|__|AA')]

Out[3]: 
  User_ID        CODE
0     A12  AAada __fa
1    F453      21 ads
2     J43      Has AA
5     L32      sad 21
6     M54  43__12 asd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string accessor for series `series.str.contains()`. Here is the [user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern)

And the code for your solution

```
pats = ['AA', '__', '\d']
mask = {}
for pat in pats:
    mask[pat] = df.CODE.str.contains(pat, regex=True)
        # regex=True is default, shown here for demonstration
    
    print()
    print(mask[pat])
```

Output

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: CODE, dtype: bool

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: CODE, dtype: bool

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: CODE, dtype: bool
```

You can use each of these masks to filter the dataframe later on. In this case it is good to keep them as separate masks, as they seem to have overlaps.